# Android MapView Loading Black Screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-mapview

Hi everyone I have an Activity which is loading after I click on an Item inside my Listview.

This activity shows the location inside a MapView like this:

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/loading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Loading Map..." />

            </FrameLayout>
```

The Problem is, that I want to show the Map to the User later on if he/she clicks on a button.

But the Activity is loading very slow and even has a black blank screen before showing anything. This looks very unprofessional, and seems wrong.

I tried making the MapView **invisible** first and show it when user hits the button, but it is loading when the activity starts.

I'am  trying following code:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_event);

        mapView = new MapView(SingleEvent.this);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.LayoutParams mapParams = new com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.LayoutParams(com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,220);
        mapContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);
        mapContainer.addView(mapView, mapParams);
```

This one is working it is showing the map, but the activity is loading to long with a black blank screen, until my activity is loaded.

[image]

Is there any way to **first** load the activity and after that load the MapView on a button click?

I'am trying to do something like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

            mapView = new MapView(SingleEvent.this);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.LayoutParams mapParams = new com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.LayoutParams(com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,220);
            mapContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);
            mapContainer.addView(mapView, mapParams);

                }
            },1000);
```

But with that code, the Map isnt loading its only showing the grey blank grid.
I think its because of the **savedInstanceState** but maybe there is a work around?

I tried to save the Bundle savedInstanceState, loading like above.

Comment: if the map is only suppose to be visible when the user preforms a certain action then there should be an activity that gets displayed when they do that action. Loading the point with no guarantee that it is going to be displayed is not a good idea

Comment: Maybe I can use services somehow?

Comment: service do not have a UI

Comment: you should probably look into using static maps with `lite mode` thats available is google play services 6.5 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). In `onCreate()`, you can set visibility to invisible. When the map is ready, `onMapReady()` will be called and you can configure map settings there.

Comment: I tried using MapFragment, but it has the same effect, that the activity is loading very slowly, with the black blank screen showing for like 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which was occurring due to hardware accelartion and largeheap. I had used these features at application level. But I removed them from the app level and used them in the activity they used. The Activity which contained `SupportMapFragment` didn't need these features. So I moved this code from Application tag to Activity in Manifest.

Issue was in `Manifest`.

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true">
```

Remove from `Manifest` and Use in the `Activity`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mycompayname.activities.SignUpActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"/>
```